# Customly layouted Pane does not fit the size of its stages viewport

Tags: java, javafx

I have a pane that layouts its child nodes customly by overriding the layoutChildren method. It simplified looks like this:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class MyPane extends Pane {
   private Label lblTitel;
   private Button btnStart;

   public MyPane(Runnable sceneChanger) {
      this.lblTitel = new Label("Title");
      lblTitel.setFont(Font.font(16));
      this.btnStart = new Button("Change Scene");
      btnStart.setOnAction(e -> sceneChanger.run());

      getChildren().addAll(lblTitel, btnStart);
   }

   @Override
   protected void layoutChildren() {
      lblTitel.setLayoutX(getWidth() / 2 - lblTitel.getWidth() / 2);
      lblTitel.setLayoutY(4);

      btnStart.setLayoutX(getWidth() / 2 - btnStart.getWidth() / 2);
      btnStart.setLayoutY(getHeight() - 4 - btnStart.getHeight());

      super.layoutChildren();
   }

}
```

Displaying that Pane as root node of a scene of a stage works fine. But when I change the scene and then change it back again, the panes size doesn't fit the stages viewport anymore.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
   private Stage window;
   private Scene firstScene;
   private Scene secondScene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
    }

    @Override
   public void start(Stage window) {
       this.window = window;
       this.firstScene = new Scene(new MyPane(() -> window.setScene(secondScene)));
       this.secondScene = new Scene(new SecondPane());
       window.setScene(firstScene);
       window.setWidth(800);
       window.setHeight(600);
       window.show();
   }

    private class SecondPane extends Pane {

      public SecondPane() {
         Button btnBack = new Button("back");
         btnBack.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(firstScene));
         getChildren().add(btnBack);
      }
    }
}
```

After changing back to the first scene the pane is far to large, you can see that by the title being more on the right side than in the horizontal center. As soon as I change the size of the window, the panes size perfectly fits the stages viewport again and everything is fine. So I added a custom increase of size to the window right after I switch scenes.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> window.setWidth(window.getWidth() + 1));
```

It works in most of the cases, but its a ridiculous solution and doesn't work when the stage is e.g. maximized.
Is there any way to make a customly layouted pane fit into the stages viewport after setting its scene to the stage, that works in all cases?

Comment: The `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods of the child nodes aren't guaranteed to give the correct results at the time you call them (basically, your `layoutChildren()` method is supposed to size the child nodes, not ask them for their size). Call the `prefWidth(...)`, `prefHeight(...)` (and maybe `minWidth(...)` etc., as needed) and then `resize(...)` the child nodes as appropriate, as well as repositioning them. It seems like you should be able to achieve this layout with standard layout panes anyway, though.

Comment: Wow the prefWidth(double) and prefHeight(double) methods are defenitely helpful to get the actual size of a node when displayed, thank you for that! It doesn't fix the issue with the size of the pane. Yes using standard layouts is definetely a good way for this simplified example, but the pane of my actual program is more complex and I really suck at dealing with existing layouts. They never look like I want them to look and I have not much control about whats going on behind the scenes of all the layout magic.

Comment: Your code actually worked fine for me on JDK 9.0.4; but generally there's a lot more to do than just overriding `layoutChildren()`. I posted an answer (which also works on my system), but I can't replicate the issue from the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the layout you give in the example code can readily be accomplished using existing layout panes. Something like

```
BorderPane myPane = new BorderPane();
myPane.setTop(lblTitel);
myPane.setBottom(btnStart);
BorderPane.setAlignment(lblTitel, Pos.CENTER);
BorderPane.setAlignment(btnStart, Pos.CENTER);
BorderPane.setMargin(lblTitle, new Insets(4, 0, 0, 0));
BorderPane.setMargin(btnStart, new Insets(0, 0, 4, 0));
```

should give you the layout you want.

In general, you should always prefer the built-in layouts to a custom layout.

If you find you really do need a custom pane, then there is a lot more work to do than simply laying out the child nodes. Your pane needs to override the methods to determine its resizable range, which means overriding the methods `computeMin/Pref/MaxWidth()` and `computeMin/Pref/MaxHeight()`. You should also determine the content bias by overriding `getContentBias()`. The `layoutChildren()` method should determine the size of the child nodes as well as their positions. It should do this by determining their preferred sizes and using those if possible, and using a size in the min-max range for each otherwise. You can determine those sizes by calling `prefWidth()`, `prefHeight()` etc on the child nodes.

Finally, to ensure the custom layout properly respects borders and padding, you should account for any insets in the layout calculations. The utility methods `snappedTop/Right/Bottom/LeftInsets()` give you the values for the insets coming from borders or padding.

Here's an example which works for me: this assumes both child nodes have `HORIZONTAL` content bias (which makes sense here), so I pass `-1` to the methods computing the width, and the computed width to the methods computing the height.

```
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;

public class MyPane extends Pane {
   private Label lblTitel;
   private Button btnStart;

   public MyPane(Runnable sceneChanger) {

      // updated to test for long text, wrapping, etc.
      this.lblTitel = new Label("This is a really long title that might end up having to span multiple lines of text");
      this.lblTitel.setWrapText(true);
      this.lblTitel.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
      lblTitel.setFont(Font.font(16));
      this.btnStart = new Button("Change Scene");
      btnStart.setOnAction(e -> sceneChanger.run());

      getChildren().addAll(lblTitel, btnStart);

   }

   @Override
   public Orientation getContentBias() {
       return Orientation.HORIZONTAL ;
   }

   @Override
   public double computePrefWidth(double height) {
       return Math.max(lblTitel.prefWidth(height), btnStart.prefWidth(height));
   }

   @Override
   public double computeMinWidth(double height) {
       return Math.max(lblTitel.minWidth(height), btnStart.minWidth(height));       
   }

   @Override
   public double computeMaxWidth(double height) {
       return Math.max(lblTitel.maxWidth(height), btnStart.maxWidth(height));       
   }   

   @Override
   public double computePrefHeight(double width) {
       return lblTitel.prefHeight(width) + btnStart.prefHeight(width) + 8 ;
   }

   @Override
   public double computeMinHeight(double width) {
       return lblTitel.minHeight(width) + btnStart.minHeight(width) + 8 ;
   }   

   @Override
   public double computeMaxHeight(double width) {
       return lblTitel.maxHeight(width) + btnStart.maxHeight(width) + 8 ;
   }

   @Override
   protected void layoutChildren() {

       double usableWidth = getWidth() - snappedLeftInset() - snappedRightInset() ;
       double usableHeight = getHeight() - snappedTopInset() - snappedBottomInset() ;

       double lblTitleWidth = lblTitel.prefWidth(-1);
       if (lblTitleWidth > usableWidth) {
           lblTitleWidth = Math.max(lblTitel.minWidth(-1), usableWidth);
       }

       double lblTitleHeight = lblTitel.prefHeight(lblTitleWidth);
       if (lblTitleHeight > usableHeight) {
           lblTitleHeight = Math.max(lblTitel.prefHeight(lblTitleWidth), usableHeight);
       }

       double lblTitleX = snappedLeftInset() + usableWidth / 2 - lblTitleWidth / 2 ;
       lblTitel.resizeRelocate(lblTitleX, 4 + snappedTopInset(), lblTitleWidth, lblTitleHeight);

       double btnStartWidth = btnStart.prefWidth(-1);
       if (btnStartWidth > usableWidth) {
           btnStartWidth = Math.max(btnStart.minWidth(-1), usableWidth);
       }

       double btnStartHeight = btnStart.prefHeight(btnStartWidth);
       if (btnStartHeight > usableHeight) {
           btnStartHeight = Math.max(btnStart.minHeight(btnStartWidth), usableHeight);
       }

       double btnStartX = snappedLeftInset() + usableWidth / 2 - btnStartWidth / 2 ;
       double btnStartY = snappedTopInset() + getHeight() - 4 - btnStartHeight ;

       btnStart.resizeRelocate(btnStartX, btnStartY, btnStartWidth, btnStartHeight);

   }


}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. All of that is helpful for me and I didn't know most of that. Anyway it didn't solve the problem. The issue is still the same when I copy your code. I tried it with jdk1.8.0_152 and jdk9.0.1.

Comment: @David It behaves the same way with the exact `MyPane` in my answer and the exact `App` class from the question?

Comment: yes, it is the exact same App class from my question and the extact same MyPane class from your answer. The only line I added is of course the package declaration.